# Capture clean Retina screenshot of web page without post production

Tags: website-design, mac, ppi, screenshot

How can I take a screenshot of a web page on a MacBook Pro with Retina Display (rMBP) that:

- Is at a reproducible size
- Looks sharp on Retina displays
- Without any browser chrome / accouterments showing
- Without having to do any manual cropping or other post-production

In the past I've used [Awesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce), but that browser extension has unfortunately fallen out of date. On my rMBP, it completely [fouls up](https://plus.google.com/u/0/115932370725995770513/posts/ZoBZaL3vSYM) under Safari and captures low res shots in Google Chrome. (As of now Awesome Screenshot is at v. 1.3.7 for Safari and 3.3.7 for Chrome.)

I ask because I have to take several shots, and update them periodically, so I need a straightforward workflow.

Comment: what is wrong with cmd +shift 3?  it allows you to select a portion of the screen and allows to you take screenshots of contextual menus, pop-ups.  maybe i'm missing something..

Comment: Unfortunately Cmd+Shift+3 fails the third & fourth bullets, "without any browser chrome / accouterments showing," and, "without having to do any manual cropping or other post-production."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## LittleSnapper

LittleSnapper is awesome. I'm 90% sure it works with Retina display Macs, but I don't have any way to confirm.

http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/

---

## Paparazzi

Paparazzi is pretty old, but free. So you could give that a shot first. I don't know how well it'll handle Retina screenshots though.

http://derailer.org/paparazzi/

---

## Photoshop

You could also take full screen Safari (or other web browser) screenshots, then batch process to crop and merge. Depending on what you're trying to do, that may be easy or quite difficult.

---

## Automator

If you're just needing to crop images, OS X's Automator is free, quick and easy to use.

Comment: Paparazzi wins! LittleSnapper apparently hasn't been updated for Retina yet, and its bookmarklet install page (from the Help menu) is currently 404. But Paparazzi seems to work (unless the web site, like apple.com, detects you as being non-retina capable and gives you low-res images). Photoshop isn't yet Retina ready, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previously mentioned apps, also take a look at [Skitch](http://skitch.com/) and [SnapzPro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/) (though that one isn't Mountain Lion compatible yet; don't know why).

Comment: SnapzProX, while not technically Mountain Lion compatible, seems to work just fine with Mountain Lion here.

Comment: Yep, you are correct. Though I've had my version crash a bunch if I do anything "fancier" than a simple screenshot. :)

Answer (score 1):

SnagIt has a Mac version which works really well. It can do browser auto-scrolling for web pages too.

http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I seem to have better luck capturing full page retina screen shots with the [Awesome Screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/) Chrome extension than with the Google Screen Capture extension that I used to use regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that LittleSnapper works on rMBP.  However, the screenshots are double resolution.  I'm not sure what you mean by "reproducible size" but if you send the screenshots to someone one a standard display, they will say "these are way too big".

I'm still trying to find out a good way to take low resolution screenshots for sharing with people who don't know what high resolution displays are.

Answer (score 1):

**This** is the correct way to take high DPI screenshots exactly how you want. The best part is you can do this on a normal DPI display. It will take full screenshots even when the high DPI rendering is bigger than the monitor.

1. Use Firefox.
2. Choose `Tools > Web Developer > Responsive Design View`.
3. Set the resolution accordingly (iPhone 6: 750x1334, iPhone 6 Plus: 1242x2208).
4. Open the hamburger menu in Firefox and set the zoom level accordingly (iPhone 6: 200%, iPhone 6 Plus: 300%). Firefox correctly changes the device pixel ratio according to the zoom level and responds to resolution media queries correctly. This gives you the correct responsive layout and high DPI rendering.
5. Press `Shift + F2` to open the console and type `screenshot`. You must use the console instead of the screenshot button to get a high DPI screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound strange, but I had a reproducible kernel panic when using the LittleSnapper bookmarklet on my MBP Retina. Apparently, capturing full-page retina screen shots of certain pages was asking my GPU to do some wacky stuff.

Tread carefully there. Otherwise, I absolutely love LittleSnapper.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. This may have been better as a comment as opposed to its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use and love [Slingshot](http://lifehacker.com/5820649/slingshot-makes-taking-screenshots-and-sharing-them-one-key+command-away), which makes a copy and puts it in my dropbox folder and copies the link to my clipboard.  Small indie developer and very nice guy.

Answer (score 0):

## [Full Page Screen Capture for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en-US)

One click and it saves an image the full length of the page and width of your browser. Only takes the page - no browser chrome.